# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“1” is not a valid UUID.']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, uuid

Whenever I am running the server I am getting the error

django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“1” is not a valid UUID.']

I have used UUID v4 to change the user id to a random id. But my code is not working.
I have deleted and re-migrated migrations many times. But no improvement at all?

how can I fix the probelm?

#models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin,BaseUserManager
import uuid



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email must be provided")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Password is not provided')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            mobile = mobile,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, password, 
**extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, 
**extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        return self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, 
**extra_fields)

# Create your User Model here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    # Abstractbaseuser has password, last_login, is_active by default
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField( max_length=250)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True) # must needed, otherwise you won't be able to 
loginto django-admin.
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # must needed, otherwise you won't be able 
to loginto django-admin.
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False) # this field we inherit from 
PermissionsMixin.

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name','mobile']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

#ERROR

[image]

Comment: You probably have user with primary key equal 1 and in user model you set primary key as UUID field. Try to #comment UUID field for while and server should run, then delete or edit users instances incorrect id field.

Comment: I have deleted all migrations and tried again after migrating the problem still exists.I dont have any user.

Comment: But i told you about instance in database, when you delete migrations it don't cause throw created instances away. You can also try reset whole database if you don't need information from there.